# Building array in controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, data-modeling

So I have a client controller like so (with only relevant code):

```
angular.module('employees').controller('EmployeesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Employees',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Employees) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        // Create new Employee
        $scope.create = function() {
            // Create new Employee object
            var employee = new Employees ({
                name: this.name,
                eid: this.eid,
                availibility: [monday: this.monday, tuesday: this.tuesday]
            });
```

With a client view (again, only code relevant to the availability array)

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label class="control-label" for="monday">Monday</label>             
                    <label class="control-label" for="start">Start</label>             
                    <label class="control-label" for="finish">Finish</label>             
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="monday" class="form-control" required>
                      <input type="time" id="start" class="form-control" required> <input type="time" id="finish" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label class="control-label" for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
                    <label class="control-label" for="start">Start</label>             
                    <label class="control-label" for="finish">Finish</label>             
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" class="form-control" required>
                      <input type="time" id="start" class="form-control" required>
                      <input type="time" id="finish" class="form-control" required>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And a server controller like so:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var employee = new Employee(req.body);
    employee.user = req.user;
    console.log(req.body);
    employee.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(employee);
        }
    });
};
```

How can I make it so that the user can update an "availability" schedule? For some reason, when I POST the form, all I am getting is the eid and name (in the req.body). What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone point me in the direction of a resource that I could use?

Also, another question that kinda has something to do with this: Can I use ngTable to style these forms? As in, can I put forms inside of a table?

Thanks everybody for the help!

P.S. I realize the code is pretty dirty (particular the HTML code + the fact that none of my controllers are actually trying to pull data from the forms yet). Again, I don't have any real reason to continue on to that part until I know why when I POST the form, the data is not included in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to try:

- Verify spelling of `availability` you have `availibility` in your create function and it could be an issue with your setup.
- It looks like you are probably using a mean.js-like setup.  I would first confirm that you have added the `availability` field to your `Employee` object.  In this case you would have to make the file `app/model/employee.server.model.js` (or where ever your model definition is to have the array)

_

```
new Employee({
    name: {type: String},
    eid: {type: String},
    availibility: {type: Array,
        default: []
    }
}
```

- Finally your `create` function looks a little funky to me.  I would use a more standard definition for the array

  ```
  // Create new Employee
  $scope.create = function() {
      // Create new Employee object
      var employee = new Employees ({
          name: this.name,
          eid: this.eid,
          availibility: [this.monday, this.tuesday]
      });
  ```